# Go Cloud Code/Docker on M1 Mac exec format error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, goland, google-cloud-code, google-cloud-intellij

I'm trying to use GoLand/Cloud Code to build a Golang microservice. But I can't seem to get the `Dockerfile` nailed down.

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 golang:1.20-alpine  AS build_base
RUN apk add --no-cache git

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /tmp/wave-service

# We want to populate the module cache based on the go.{mod,sum} files.
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Unit tests
# CGO_ENABLED=0 go test -v

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build -o ./out/wave-service ./wave_microservice.go

# Start fresh from a smaller image
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 golang:1.20-alpine
RUN apk add ca-certificates

COPY --from=build_base /tmp/wave-service/out/wave-service /app/wave-service
RUN chmod a+x /app/wave-service

# This container exposes port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the binary program produced by `go install`
CMD ["/app/wave-service"]
```

Returns the error

```
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/wave-service: container wave-service-container is backing off waiting to restart
    - pod/wave-service-565995d854-hwhsm: container wave-service-container is backing off waiting to restart
      > [wave-service-565995d854-hwhsm wave-service-container] exec /app/wave-service: exec format error
```

I've tried playing around with architectures and OS variables, but I can't seem to find what's going on here.

EDIT:

skaffold.yml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta5
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: wave-service
      context: wave-service
      platforms: ["linux/amd64"]
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile

manifests:
  rawYaml:
    - k8s-pod.yaml
```

k8s-pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: wave-service
spec:
  containers:
    - name: wave-service
      image: wave-service
```

Comment: Are you deploying this to Kubernetes?  Is the cluster running x86 or ARM hardware?  That seems like error you get if you have an x86 cluster, but your Dockerfile is pretty explicit about building an ARM image.  (Also consider building the final image `FROM alpine`; you do not need the Go toolchain to run the compiled binary, and this will make the final image much smaller.)

Comment: My M1 Mac is an arm machine. 

I know I can make it smaller, but I need something to work before I start optimizing.

Comment: Try to use non-alpine Go image to see if it works.

Comment: Echoing the comments above. Additionally, Skaffold (the tool Cloud Code uses under the hood) has built in support for cross platform builds: https://skaffold.dev/docs/builders/cross-platform . If you are deploying to GKE, for example, Skaffold should detect the architecture of your target cluster automatically.

Comment: So I tried both `ubuntu:latest` and `golang:latest` and still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have any platform indicators in your skaffold.yaml? you could try adding `platforms: ["linux/amd64"]` to force it to build an x86 image (see skaffold.dev/docs/builders/cross-platform for more details).

Comment: So I don't have a skaffold.yaml, I'm trying to find a simple example to base off of, but I'm unfamiliar with it

Comment: I've added a `skaffold.yaml` and `k8s-pod.yaml` to the problem, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem wasn't docker, it was my main go file. It wasn't using the package `main` so go never found the proper entry point to compile, Changing that worked!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the fact M1 Mac doesn't allow to deploy images built for `amd64` because they are not compatible with `arm64`.

What you need to do is to force the `trustBuilder` to deploy with buildpacks. Setting `trustBuilder=true` instructs the pack library to trust the lifecycle binary that is inside the builder image, by mounting the registry credentials into the image and allowing it to perform the image export. In this way, all buildpacks can see the credentials.

In your `skaffold.yml` file add the `trustBuilder` option:

```
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: wave-service
      buildpacks:
        builder: gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1
        trustBuilder: true
```

For completeness, I point out [the github issue](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pull/7629) related to the fix added in the latest versions of skaffold to check the commit code that solved the issue.

Comment: So the problem was actually a go error. I had the main function labeled in the wrong package. Changing that solved my problem.